# Sinon Stub standalone utility function in a module

Tags: javascript, sinon

I am writing a test using Sinon, the basic flow of the program is

```
foo(){
  return Promise.resolve(x);
}

module.exports = function (){
  ...
  foo();
  ...
}
```

In my test i import the module, i want to stub `foo()`, is there a way i can fake the function call and return something else?

Comment: Foo is private to the module. Without a structural change I don't see how.

Comment: Stubbed the function inside the private function that was an object method that was returning data.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Actually it is a bad practice because the declared private function is a part of the module you are testing. However you can substitute any module local variable using [rewire](https://github.com/jhnns/rewire).